# Beamer headline navigation

Tags: beamer, navigation

I have a question about a beamer headline. I'm not sure whether what I'm trying to do will make any sense to you but I'm going to ask it anyway.

What I want is some sort of a section navigation with dots as using with `\insertnavigation` but in the following way: e.g.

> Introduction ooooo
> Background ooo

Well it is possible to put the sections in such a way using `\insertsectionnavigation` but I cannot put the dots where I want them.
With `\insertnavigation` I can do the following

> Introduction          Background         Theory       Conclusion
>
> oooooo                ooooo              ooooo

Is it possible to do what I want to do or do I need to create my own theme and so forth.
Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: Without a MWE showing at least some of what you have tried, this is very unlikely to be answered. I'm marking as 'unclear' on that basis: please edit and I'll reopen.